Clustered column store not aligning GUIDs to segments despite ordering
I have a data set that I want to place in a clustered column store and optimize it for segment elimination when accessing it by a column called SubjectId which is defined as uniqueidentifier type.
I'm using an Azure SQL database with a compatibility level of 16. I have confirmed this same behavior in SQL Server Developer Edition 2022. According to the documentation, this version should support segment elimination based on a uniqueidentifier column.
Following various best practices, I first take my data set and create a rowstore clustered index ordered by that SubjectId:
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [MyData_CCI] 
ON [dbo].[MyData_CCS] (SubjectId)
WITH (MAXDOP = 1);

I then create the clustered document store using the DROP EXISTING option:
CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX [MyData_CCI]
ON [dbo].[MyData_CCS]
WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON, MAXDOP = 1);

The resulting segments don't appear to be aligned whatsoever to this SubjectId:

And when I try and query the data using a single SubjectId in the where clause, the statistics show zero segment elimination:

(44 rows affected)
Table 'MyData_CCS'. Scan count 1, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 2769, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'MyData_CCS'. Segment reads 77, segment skipped 0.

What am I doing wrong here? Isn't SQL Server 2022+ (and therefore SQL Azure?) supposed to support uniqueidentifier for segment elimination and predicate push down? As I said, this also happens with SQL Dev Edition 2022, so I don't think it's an Azure thing.
You can repro this yourself with the following schema/data generation script:
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MyData]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[MyData]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyData](
    [SubjectId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [SomeDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [SomeInteger] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SomeString] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

-- Create a temporary table to store unique SubjectId values
DROP TABLE #SubjectIds
CREATE TABLE #SubjectIds (
    SubjectId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
);
GO

WITH NumberSeries AS (
    SELECT 1 AS Number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Number + 1
    FROM NumberSeries
    WHERE Number < 42000
)
INSERT INTO #SubjectIds (SubjectId)
SELECT NEWID()
FROM NumberSeries
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

-- Insert 21 million rows using cross join
INSERT INTO MyData (SubjectId, SomeDateTime, SomeInteger, SomeString)
SELECT 
    s.SubjectId,
    DATEADD(SECOND, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 31536000), '2020-01-01'), -- Random date within a year
    ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 1000000), -- Random integer
    REPLICATE(N'A', 100) -- Example string, adjust as needed
FROM 
    #SubjectIds s
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP (500) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS n FROM master..spt_values) AS x;

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [MyData_CCI] 
ON [dbo].[MyData] (SubjectId)
WITH (MAXDOP = 1, DROP_EXISTING = ON);
GO

CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX [MyData_CCI]
ON [dbo].[MyData]
WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON, MAXDOP = 1);

--Show Segment data
select s.Name as SchemaName, 
       t.Name as TableName,
       i.Name as IndexName,
       c.name as ColumnName,
       c.column_id as ColumnId,
       cs.segment_id as SegmentId,
       cs.min_data_id as MinValue,
       cs.max_data_id as MaxValue
  from sys.schemas s
  join sys.tables t
    on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
  join sys.partitions as p  
    on p.object_id = t.object_id   
  join sys.indexes as I
    on i.object_id = p.object_id
   and i.index_id = p.index_id
  join sys.index_columns as ic
    on ic.[object_id] = I.[object_id]
   and ic.index_id = I.index_id   
  join sys.columns c
    on c.object_id = t.object_id
   and c.column_id = ic.column_id
  join sys.column_store_segments cs
    on cs.hobt_id = p.hobt_id
   and cs.column_id = ic.index_column_id 
WHERE t.Name = 'MyData' AND c.Name = 'SubjectId'
ORDER BY cs.segment_id

Update/Resolution
This was resolved via discovering that the min/max id meta data is only for numeric types. For GUIDs, strings, etc. post SQL 2022, you need to look at the min_deep_data and max_deep_data columns. In my case, these were not populated despite having created these column stores brand new on a level 16 compatibility DB in SQL Azure. I do not know why that's the case, but it is.
I was forced to do a REBUILD with MAXDOP 1 on the affected column stores to populate this meta data, after which I saw more appropriate segment elimination. Specifically:
ALTER INDEX [MyData_CCI] ON [dbo].[MyData] REBUILD WITH (MAXDOP = 1);


I dunno, this worked fine for me.
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MyData]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[MyData]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyData](
    [SubjectId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [SomeDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [SomeInteger] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SomeString] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

-- Create a temporary table to store unique SubjectId values
DROP TABLE #SubjectIds
CREATE TABLE #SubjectIds (
    SubjectId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
);
GO

WITH NumberSeries AS (
    SELECT 1 AS Number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Number + 1
    FROM NumberSeries
    WHERE Number < 42000
)
INSERT INTO #SubjectIds (SubjectId)
SELECT NEWID()
FROM NumberSeries
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

-- Insert 21 million rows using cross join
INSERT INTO MyData (SubjectId, SomeDateTime, SomeInteger, SomeString)
SELECT 
    s.SubjectId,
    DATEADD(SECOND, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 31536000), '2020-01-01'), -- Random date within a year
    ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 1000000), -- Random integer
    REPLICATE(N'A', 100) -- Example string, adjust as needed
FROM 
    #SubjectIds s
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP (500) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS n FROM master..spt_values) AS x;

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [MyData_CCI] 
ON [dbo].[MyData] (SubjectId)
WITH (MAXDOP = 1);
GO

CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX [MyData_CCI]
ON [dbo].[MyData]
WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON, MAXDOP = 1);

set statistics io on

select *
from Mydata
where SubjectId = '15A4815B-DDD3-48BB-84DE-A578663D8D91'


/*
Table 'MyData'. Scan count 4, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 51224, lob physical reads 9, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 80541, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'MyData'. Segment reads 10, segment skipped 11.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.

*/

SELECT @@version

Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM) - 16.0.1000.6 (X64) 

Maybe the segment thingy depends on which GUIDs you are selecting?
Edit, had to do a new batch:
select *
from Mydata
where SubjectId = 'B52D5BC0-33B6-44F9-87C3-1CAFD7FDDEA5'

Output:



SchemaName
TableName
IndexName
ColumnName
ColumnId
SegmentId
MinValue
MaxValue
min_deep_data
max_deep_data
encoding_type
primary_dictionary_id
secondary_dictionary_id
row_count




dbo
MyData
MyData_CCI
SubjectId
1
0
26
24899
100031AAB70512CE9244B9092BFA4B2EF4B1
100035979016BB401242B0796DC167CB1F9E
3
0
1
1048576


dbo
MyData
MyData_CCI
SubjectId
1
1
27
25837
100035979016BB401242B0796DC167CB1F9E
1000203A7982506BAF45A5CA963EBE4637AF
3
0
1
1048576


dbo
MyData
MyData_CCI
SubjectId
1
2
24
26749
1000203A7982506BAF45A5CA963EBE4637AF
10004FD8C586BF0F5D4BB109D296FDD032B3
3
0
1
1048576


dbo
MyData
MyData_CCI
SubjectId
1
3
25
27685
10004FD8C586BF0F5D4BB109D296FDD032B3
1000EBD81ADB9A00F94DA589FE85EC39C5C3
3
0
1
1048576


dbo
MyData
MyData_CCI
SubjectId
1
4
22
28601
1000B8640879660E6541A25E04E74363E39C
1000F8CC2A1D96B30B4C8687FF1DAC082C2C
3
0
1
1048576


dbo
MyData
MyData_CCI
SubjectId
1
5
19
29482
10003F8ACDB56E2CBB4E9C7935F65E78D3A9
1000CD9C58D6438CB845A3CE79EC437123E9
3
0
1
1048576


dbo
MyData
MyData_CCI
SubjectId
1
6
20
30368
1000CD9C58D6438CB845A3CE79EC437123E9
1000006AB21D01564048B767D68755ED8FFF
3
0
1
1048576


dbo
MyData
MyData_CCI
SubjectId
1
7
21
31299
1000006AB21D01564048B767D68755ED8FFF
1000F151931B7AA63844A40FE37382B66DA4
3
0
1
1048576


dbo
MyData
MyData_CCI
SubjectId
1
8
17
32227
10002998463928C0034F8DC7067F49C9C803
1000E8AF680F3BA2D340A76AFFFE92C5D579
3
0
1
1048576


dbo
MyData
MyData_CCI
SubjectId
1
9
18
33119
1000C14ABF7C819F784E952E3BD91E0D4059
10008733320FD434364890D9946020C5621E
3
0
1
1048576


dbo
MyData
MyData_CCI
SubjectId
1
10
15
33983
10008733320FD434364890D9946020C5621E
10000A7AFD6104DE574C9561F4634A3D7AEE
3
0
1
1048576


dbo
MyData
MyData_CCI
SubjectId
1
11
13
34899
1000C6A9B411DD37C941A17E00057ABE0045
1000750EC694DA9E964CBC4CF5956C3450BE
3
0
1
1048576


dbo
MyData
MyData_CCI
SubjectId
1
12
14
35785
10000F82C113010FAB4699210D5873CEF401
1000A2093746B569CE43A5DD4E611EC2232B
3
0
1
1048576


dbo
MyData
MyData_CCI
SubjectId
1
13
11
36677
1000A2093746B569CE43A5DD4E611EC2232B
1000ECAD306ED4688C4686719B0832A5C345
3
0
1
1048576


dbo
MyData
MyData_CCI
SubjectId
1
14
12
37569
1000ECAD306ED4688C4686719B0832A5C345
1000D8255C9755EB7E41BD5AA804D4D9DF14
3
0
1
1048576


dbo
MyData
MyData_CCI
SubjectId
1
15
9
38474
1000A155D38E3D1A8540884B1115D3C54DD2
100012931F70BB180A4EBD61C7D33663A9F6
3
0
1
1048576


dbo
MyData
MyData_CCI
SubjectId
1
16
7
39324
1000EC8501B92CE62847875B143C5C24915B
10006FC55B8556D70E4D84D85BC913E5F067
3
0
1
1048576


dbo
MyData
MyData_CCI
SubjectId
1
17
8
40220
10006FC55B8556D70E4D84D85BC913E5F067
10001528C2B94ED06E40B365ADB168364FC4
3
0
1
1048576


dbo
MyData
MyData_CCI
SubjectId
1
18
5
41104
10001528C2B94ED06E40B365ADB168364FC4
1000A4772319590F5E48BCBCBA2771741A25
3
0
1
1048576


dbo
MyData
MyData_CCI
SubjectId
1
19
4
41981
10005578600DA8DCA34A801A16570EDAEBB5
100012931F70BB180A4EBD61C7D33663A9F6
3
0
1
1048576


dbo
MyData
MyData_CCI
SubjectId
1
20
532
42006
1000DDEAACB5C5E57D4C9B131CAF92E77395
1000AFF3D2B670ACBB46B04E1CEB27BFFAD0
3
0
1
28480



Table 'MyData'. Scan count 4, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 10751, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 10, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'MyData'. Segment reads 8, segment skipped 13.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.


Interesting. That said, given 500 rows per guid, I would expect at most2 segments being read and the rest skipped. What does your segment max/min query look like?

Had dropped the table, so had to redo it, but will add it. I have a feeling that segment min/max values don't really correspond to the underlying values, but i could be wrong

Even if the values don't correspond directly, I would not expect having to read 8 segments.

It seems like the original index order isn't respected when the ColumnStore-index is created, so the values kinda get jumbled together, which explains why it reads so many segments. Although, this can still happen, as the order isn't maintained over time when new data is added. Although, it's still good some are getting eliminated. Did you test this with non-GUID data types? How does it look there?

I've now confirmed I, too, see at least some segments being skipped in Azure SQL DB, which provides this isn't a "GUIDs cant be used for segment skipping issue" and is instead an issue of GUIDs not being properly aligned by segment.

So I think the min/max id columns don't mean anything for GUID data types, but there is a new "min_deep_data" and "max_deep_data" column that apparently do, although I still don't see alignment. I also found this Brent Ozar article complaining that sorting is best effort as so segment overlap will be common with larger data sets (which my primary one is, but this test one really isn't), so I'm still not sure what's going on! https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2022/07/columnstore-indexes-are-finally-sorted-in-sql-server-2022/

Ok. So on the small test data set I am getting both populated "Min/Max Deep Values" and some level of segment elimination, but on my larger test data sets (20GB+ and 600GB+) the Min/Max deep values are NOT being populated even after rebuilds.... so zero segment elimination!

Ok, so doing an index rebuild like the following seems to have "fixed" this in an Azure SQL based data set: ALTER INDEX [MyData_CCI] ON [dbo].[MyData] REBUILD WITH (MAXDOP = 1);

Wow really, that's strange, because if anything, the original order should've been lost after a rebuild? Perhaps this is one of those "in preview" features? :)

Gonna give you credit since you were the only one to try and help :)
